# Why are executable created from python scripts detected as viruses?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cx-freeze, py2exe, virus

I have tried PyInstaller, py2exe and cx_Freeze to create a windows executable from a Python script. I then tried to check the produced executable for viruses using VirusTotal. It gave the following results:

PyInstaller: 18 / 69 detected viruses

py2exe: 4 / 68 detected viruses

cx_Freeze: 1 / 68 detected viruses

It seems that cx_Freeze is the most safe, but PyInstaller is disastrous.

I have searched on the internet and they say that they are all false positives, but it is not easy to convince a client that 18 antiviruses gave false positive.

My question is: Why are executable created from python scripts detected  as viruses? What is the technical issue behind this?

Thank you.